# How is starting wealth (money) chart determined for Ultramodern 5 Redux?

Tags: character-creation, wealth, ultramodern5

I recently got the PDF and Book for *Ultramodern 5 Redux*.

I can't seem to find a starting wealth (money) chart; is there one?

If not, is there an simple alternate system (like how D20 Modern had a Wealth score and you roll a d20 plus the Wealth score over/vs an item's DC to see if you are able to buy it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Look at the page on backgrounds

Ultramodern 5 provides starting wealth as part of the character backgrounds (page 12):

> These following backgrounds denote where you came from, usually detailing the first few years of your life. It may not determine your current status, only that which was given to you upon your birth. You can start wealthy and lose it all or be born into poverty, only to find wealth through actions rather than luck.

For example, the Affluent background comes with this starting equipment:

> A set of fine clothes, **$200** in a fine leather wallet

while a Drifter gets

> A set of common clothes, backpack, bed-roll, blanket, **$5** in coins

This is different from the D&D PHB, where starting equipment still was part of the class, not the background.